# How to use SqlDataSource with button on click to get results from gridview

Tags: sql, sql-server, button, gridview, sqldatasource

My overall goal is to be able to type in information into my textbox and click a button to search and get results from the database using gridview. So far I have my `SqlDataSource` SQL statement set up. I need to figure out how to link my button on click event with my `SqlDataSource` and `Textbox`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=********;Initial Catalog=*******;User ID=*******;Password=*******");
     connection.Open();
 }
```

I am not sure how to use my `SqlDataSource` that I have already set up.

Updated Code:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("*******");
        SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            dt.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT* FROM  Core.Form_Section_SubSection_Item_Rel WHERE ([DataCollectionPeriodID] = @DataCollectionPeriodID)", sqlCon);
            dt.Fill(ds);
            sqlCon.Close();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting data with a stored procedure?

Comment: @paabobo No Just a simple SQL select from where statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will advice you use are stored proc with a parameter and do something like below but you can  change this to use your select query, just change commandtype

```
  using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
{ 

 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) 
{ 
 sqlCon.Open(); 
 cmd.Connection = sqlCon; 
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT* FROM Core.Form_Section_SubSection_Item_Rel WHERE         DataCollectionPeriodID = @DataCollectionPeriodID"; 
 cmd.CommandTimeout = 30; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DataCollectionPeriodID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text 
SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
 dt.Fill(ds); 

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) 
{ 
 if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) 
 { 
 GridView1.DataSource = ds; 
  GridView1.DataBind(); 
 } 
} 
 } 
 }
```

Comment: Ok so I changed it to use my selectquery but the gridview does not change.

Comment: you didnt set gridview.DataSource = ds before doing gridview.DataBind

Comment: in my GridView property DataSourceID is already set and when I ran it it said DataSource and DataSourceID cannot be used at the same time.

Comment: take the datasouceid out and just do the datasource

Comment: Done. Now when I load it on Chrome, the gridView is not shown when the page loads and when I do try to search it still doesnt show up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55775/discussion-between-paabobo-and-user3339242).